# How to get url that includes a dot

Tags: php

I'm trying to get the url from sample below link using php get but I'm missing something.

Example link:

```
example.com/go/?url=http://example2.com
```

and using the below code:

```
<?php
$url = $_GET["url"];
echo $url;
?>
```

and all i can see is 403 error,
I see now that error is from dot (.) in url, but how can I correct it?

Comment: First of all, you're echoing out a variable that doesn't exist.

Comment: sorry, updated, but same error

Comment: I'm having trouble following your question.  *Where* are you receiving a 403 response code?  How is a 403 response code related to the issue of not getting the `url` parameter correctly?  What is the value of `$url` you are printing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should [`urlencode`](https://www.php.net/urlencode) the parameter to ensure its not being interpreted wrong, when sending the request to the server and use [`urldecode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) on the server to revert it back.

Also the [403 error code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403) is the web serving telling you permission denied for some reason you have to investigate. Maybe look at the logs for your webserver.

Comment: Then, in PHP use urldecode()